# How do I extract the content of quoted strings from a file

Tags: text-processing, perl

have a file which looks like this:

```
anm="12S123S" family="" type="Std" product="" name="nand" allow="yes"
anm="12321 S=" family="" type="Std" product="" name="dan" need="No"
anm="SWED" family="" type="Std" product="" name="dmr" test="clasic"
```

Output should be

```
12S123S
12321 S=
SWED
```

Comment: `sed 's/[^"]*"\([^"]*\).*/\1/'`

Comment: `awk -F\" '{print $2}' file`

Comment: `grep -Po 'anm="\K[^"]*' file`

Comment: @jasonwryan Nice! Same `cut -d\" -f2`

Comment: how can the same thing be done in perl

Comment: @sudobean - if you can do it w/ `cut` you almost definitely don't want `perl`.

Comment: @mikeserv I'm not convinced about those `cut/sed/awk` solutions. They are all clear and nice, but at the same time assume that extracted string is exactly at certain position in the line. That may not be true all the time. BTW, one way with perl: `perl -pe 's/.*anm="([^"]*).*/\1/' file`.

Comment: @jimmij - the assumption is that the string is in the first quoted position on the line. But I get it - the `perl` there follows the other pattern: the `anm=`. Good point. With `sed`: `sed '/\n/P;//!s/anm="\([^"]*\)/\n\1\n/;D'` which would print as many values for `anm` as might occur on a line and nothing else. The `perl` might want `?` one of those not-greedy modifiers to keep it from eating any preceding `anm=` bits.

Comment: `perl -nE '/anm="(.*?)"/ and say $1'`

Answer (score 2):

To collect all comments to OP:

by `cut` (set field delimiter to `"` and print second field just from lines where delimiter exist):

```
cut -sd\" -f2
```

by `grep` [jimmij](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/80886/jimmij) (find the pattern and print it part after `\K` only):

```
grep -Po 'anm="\K[^"]*'
```

by `awk` [jasonwryan](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/6761/jasonwryan) (set field delimiter to `"` and print second field):

```
awk -F\" '{print $2}'
```

by `sed` (substitute all line by *reverse match* (inside brackets `()`) which match everything not `"` after first `"` and print lines where such substitution has made only):

```
sed -n 's/[^"]*"\([^"]*\).*/\1/p'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the `anm="..."` part with grep like this:

```
grep -Eo 'anm="[^"]*"' file
```

The `-o` option to grep only outputs the part of a line that matches.

Then remove both the `anm="` at the beginning and `"` at the end of each line:

```
grep -Eo 'anm="[^"]*"' file | sed -e 's/^anm=\"//' -e 's/\"$//'
```

Comment: If you put expression inside quotes `'` there is no need to escape `"`. Secondary (I think so) there is good practique to do task by one command: do not mix `sed`,`grep`,`awk`,`cut`... All this commands have similar functionality and (in most cases surely) able to do task by alone.

Comment: Thanks Daniel! i am running the following on a 30gig file and its running from last 40+ mins                                                 grep -Eo 'anm="[^"]*"' file | sed -e 's/^anm=\"//' -e 's/\"$//'